# Add Footer to the left column of the first page LaTeX

Tags: header-footer

please any one help me to make a notice to appear only on the first page under the left column as per attached photo [image]

Comment: What document class are you using? That might make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under a `twocolumn` article, you can insert `\footnotetext[<num>]` while still in the first column. This will set a footnote without the footnote mark. Below I've set the footnote to be printed as `\fnsymbol`, which follows the sequence `*`, `†`, `‡`, `§`, `¶`, `‖`, `**`, `††`, `‡‡`, (error), in sync with [the title's `\thanks`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289539/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{A title}
\author{An author\thanks{Some reference to this author}}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\sloppy% Just for this example

\maketitle

\footnotetext[1]{Here is some footnote at the bottom of the first column that might reference the author.}%
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: i used the \thanks method, but the line doesn't appear

Comment: @AmrShata: I assume it's okay though, as you've accepted my answer. If not, what `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}

Comment: @AmrShata: Under `conference` mode, `\thanks` doesn't work. However, you'll still get the "footnote" if you use my technique. Not sure whether that suffices.

Comment: yeah i managed to add the notice using \thanks, but the line doesn't appear i tried the other method too, still i can't get the line

Comment: @AmrShata: Within [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls) you'll find the following line of code: "The IEEE does not use footnote rules" after which they set `\def\footnoterule{}`. If you really need it (for whatever reason, add `\makeatletter \def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@}\makeatother` to your preamble.