# Customizing the symbol next to the author's name in a document

Tags: footnotes, author, footmisc

I would like to choose the symbol appearing next to the author's name of a document (for example, I would like to put a dagger instead of a star). Here is an example showing how one can proceed to choose the symbol for the command *\footnote* : [Symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers)

Problem is that it fails when used in the *\author* environment. I can not use the above example if I use *\thanks* instead of *\footnote*.

Here is a minimal example :

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,two column]{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


\begin{document}
\author{Nicolas\footnote[2]{Ask a question}}
\title{Minimal Example}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `article` documentclass offers the `\thanks` command for footnotes within the `author`. These footnotes are automatically labelled by a symbol chosen from the following list (in the given order):  `*`, `†`, `‡`, `§`, `¶`, `‖`, `**`, `††`, `‡‡`.

If you want your first footnote to be labelled by `†` rather than `*`, you could change the following original definition:

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
```

to:

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
```

where I have simply deleted `*\or` from the sequence.

The above code can be applied as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,two column]{article}

    \makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
    \makeatother


\begin{document}
\author{Nicolas\thanks{Ask a question}}
\title{Minimal Example}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a more in depth discussion on how the `\thanks` command works, you can have a look at the [Werner's excellent answer to 'How does \thanks work in LaTeX article class?'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289545/134144)

Comment: Note that, in some cultures, a dagger placed immediately after a person’s name indicates that the person is deceased.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler approach than @leandriis' is to just set the counter appropriately (easier as long as you have just one note). So you pretend to have one footnote before and latex uses the second footnote symbol.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,two column]{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\author{\stepcounter{footnote}Nicolas\thanks{Ask a question}}
\title{Minimal Example}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]