# Why does \renewcommand{\dagger}{*} not apply to \thanks?

Tags: author

I know that I can adjust my `\thanks` symbols by overriding `fnsymbols` as described here: [Customizing the symbol next to the author's name in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455140/customizing-the-symbol-next-to-the-authors-name-in-a-document?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But it seems to me that just re-defining the dagger should also work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\dagger}{*}
\title{Test}
\author{Author 1\thanks{Thanks 1} \and Author 2\thanks{I-should-be-next-to-an-asterisk}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle 
Here the dagger is replaced correctly: $\dagger$
\end{document}
```

Which correctly replaces the dagger with an asterisk in the main text, but not in the title:

[image: screenshot]

What does wrong here? I tried moving the `renewcommand` up or down, to now avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default footnote symbol uses `\textdagger` not `\dagger`. As your example shows, `\dagger` is a math mode command.

Comment: How did you find that out? The definition in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455140/customizing-the-symbol-next-to-the-authors-name-in-a-document?noredirect=1&lq=1 suggests that it's \dagger, not \textdagger.

Comment: @bonifaz I have been maintaining the latex sources since 1993, I have some idea about some of the definitions:-)

Comment: I see, makes sense :-) I was just curious how I could find out myself in the future.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line (`>` represents the prompt) you can issue

```latex
> latexdef -s fnsymbol
% latex.ltx, line 2234:
\def\fnsymbol#1{\expandafter\@fnsymbol\csname c@#1\endcsname}
```

OK, we need to know what `\@fnsymbol` does:

```latex
> latexdef -s @fnsymbol
% latex.ltx, line 2254:
\def\@fnsymbol#1{%
   \ifcase#1\or \TextOrMath\textasteriskcentered *\or
   \TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger\or
   \TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger \or
   \TextOrMath \textsection  \mathsection\or
   \TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph\or
   \TextOrMath \textbardbl \|\or
   \TextOrMath {\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{**}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}\else
   \@ctrerr \fi
}%
```

This means that if `\fnsymbol` appears in text mode, it associates `\textdagger` for the number 2.

For the specific application you might consider to redefine `\@fnsymbol`, so as not to redefine `\textdagger`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@fnsymbol\@fnsymbol
\renewcommand\@fnsymbol[1]{\ifcase#1\or*\or*\else\@ctrerr\fi}
\newcommand{\restorefnsymbol}{\let\@fnsymbol\latex@fnsymbol}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textheight}{7cm} % just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Author 1\thanks{Thanks 1} \and 
  Author 2\thanks{I-should-be-next-to-an-asterisk}}

\maketitle
\restorefnsymbol

Here we have a dagger: $\dagger$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer!! Definitely useful to understand the background in the future.