# How to change the footnote symbol of \thanks in KOMA-script?

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, scrreprt

By default, [`KOMA-script`](https://komascript.de/%7Emkohm/scrguide-en.pdf) uses a star (*) symbol for the first occurence of the `\thanks` command, which is typically used to denote affiliations of authors.

I don't like the star and would like to change it to maybe a dagger (†) or some other symbol of my choice. I don't think any kind of option is mentioned in the documentation, but maybe someone knows a solution anyway?

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrreprt}
\title{Title needed to compile}
\author{John Doe\thanks{Blackacre University}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Take a look a this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455140/ It's for the `article` class, but you might still find it useful.

Comment: @Ingmar Good find, `\stepcounter{footnote}` was all it took.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, KoMa classes don't seem to be compatible with `footmisc`, that would allow for defining your own style for footnote symbols.

You can change the definition of `\@fnsymbol` in order to remove the asterisks.

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
% latex.ltx, line 8262:
\def\@fnsymbol#1{%
   \ifcase#1\or
   %\TextOrMath\textasteriskcentered *\or
   \TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger\or
   \TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger \or
   \TextOrMath \textsection  \mathsection\or
   \TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph\or
   \TextOrMath \textbardbl \|\or
   %\TextOrMath {\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{**}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}\else
   \@ctrerr \fi
}
\makeatother


\title{Title needed to compile}
\author{John Doe\thanks{Blackacre University}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a standard class:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\DefineFNsymbols*{noasterisk}{
   {\TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger}%
   {\TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger}%
   {\TextOrMath \textsection  \mathsection}%
   {\TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph}%
   {\TextOrMath \textbardbl \|}%
   {\TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}}%
   {\TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}}%
}
\setfnsymbol{noasterisk}

\title{Title needed to compile}
\author{John Doe\thanks{Blackacre University}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? The KOMA docs specifically claim `footmisc` compatibility a couple of times – specifically "Version 5.3d to 5.5b", though, so this might no longer be the case.

Comment: @Ingmar I tried…

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll accept this answer since it offers a fully customizeable solution without external packages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `footmisc` together with KOMA-Script classes, if you redo the `\deffootnote` of the KOMA-Script classes documented in the manual, after loading `footmisc`:

```latex
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{%
\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}%
}
\DefineFNsymbols*{noasterisk}{
   {\TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger}%
   {\TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger}%
   {\TextOrMath \textsection  \mathsection}%
   {\TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph}%
   {\TextOrMath \textbardbl \|}%
   {\TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}}%
   {\TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}}%
}
\setfnsymbol{noasterisk}

\title{Title needed to compile}
\author{John Doe\thanks{Blackacre University}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ingmar in a comment, from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455147/) I found that a simple `\stepcounter{footnote}` does the trick.

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrreprt}
\title{Title needed to compile}
\author{John Doe\stepcounter{footnote}\thanks{Blackacre University}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```