# Equal contribution in the first page

Tags: header-footer, article

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Thermodynamic of black holes}

\author{Albert Einstein$^1$}
\author{Roger Penrose$^2$}
\author{Rabindranath Tagore$^3$}


\affil{$^1$Princeton, USA
\\
$^2$Oxford, UK
\\
$^3$Delhi, India
}
\affil{Correspondence: r.tagore@gmail.com}

\begin{document}
```

which looks like

[image]

How can I put the sentence "These authors contributed equally to this work." for the first two authors, above the email of corresponding author? Or, any other places which is more common? (for example, after the corresponding author's email?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `authblk` package, commands `\affil` and `\author` have an optional argument. You dont have to use `$^1$` :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Thermodynamic of black holes}

\author[1]{Albert Einstein}
\author[2]{Roger Penrose}
\author[3]{Rabindranath Tagore}

\affil[1]{Princeton, USA}
\affil[2]{Oxford, UK}
\affil[3]{Delhi, India}

\affil[1,2]{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil[3]{Correspondence: r.tagore@gmail.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 nice package, first I have heard of it, thanks!

Comment: You can put a `\vspace` in `\affil` command : `\affil[3]{Delhi, India \vspace{1em}}`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{authblk}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@contributions{These authors contributed equally to this work.\textsuperscript{1}\textsuperscript{,2}}

\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 0.5em%
    \@contributions% % <----
    \vskip 1.5em
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\title{Thermodynamic of black holes}

\author{Albert Einstein\textsuperscript{1}}
\author{Roger Penrose\textsuperscript{2}}
\author{Rabindranath Tagore\textsuperscript{3}}


\affil{\textsuperscript{1}Princeton, USA
\\
\textsuperscript{2}Oxford, UK
\\
\textsuperscript{3}Delhi, India
}
\affil{Correspondence: r.tagore@gmail.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text
\end{document}
```

This answer redefines `\@maketitle` using help from [Werner's answer to How does \thanks work in LaTeX article class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289545/273733). I didn't notice that you were manually adding the `affiliations` to the authors via `$^1$` which simplifies it. You can change the distances between `\maketitle` entries by modifying `\vskip` values.

Also, I changed your superscript notion from `$^1$` to `\textsuperscript{1}` which I prefer (I am not sure if it is essential but it is better then using math mode in-text I think?). Modify the values in `\@contributions` to change to other authors as you wish, hope this is helpful.